# Quicker and quieter than a mouse, what am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Quicker and quieter than a mouse,
>   You may find me in your house
>   if you happen to have a cat,
>   But a classroom is my original habitat.
>   If you haven't guessed yet, no need to pout
>   I'll happily point the answer out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is

> A Laser Pointer

Why would you happen to find it in your house if you have a cat

> Cats love to play with laser pointers

Quieter and quicker than a mouse

> Quiet check, quick check

Clasroom

> used to point out things on a board

Last Clue

> Happily point the answer out!

Comment: it is a laser pointer! well done, and welcome to puzzling! I know this is a fairly easy riddle but for future reference it's good to get into the habit of including a little bit of explanation in your answer for how it fits the clues.

Comment: Thanks :). Just added the explanation. I had the answer in a jiffy but apparently there is a 30 character minimum limit. This is my first answer :)

Answer (score 4):

It's a:

> Laser Pointer

Quicker and quieter than a mouse

> They are quiet

You may find me in your house

if you happen to have a cat,

> Used for playing with cats

But a classroom is my original habitat.

> Used to point in classrooms

If you haven't guessed yet, no need to pout

I'll happily point the answer out.

> Again, it is used for pointing

Comment: Well done! This is by far the most well thought out answer, kudos! Unfortunately I can't accept all of them and Karan got there just a tiny bit sooner, so I'm going to have to go with her answer.